# Trying to delete potential outliers in a huge database using R.

Tags: r, statistics

im trying to delete potential outliers in R. 
My problem is the next one:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=9286177980

When I apply a boxplot, my newdata got more potential outliers than the original data. Im working with 500.000 observations, so i need to solve this to do properly my analysis.

I know that when the distribution is not uniform, like this case, we can work with the 2nd and 3rd quartile, but if i do that, i loose the 20-30% of my data.

Thank you.

Comment: Link is redirecting to the main site. (https://www.photobox.co.uk/a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solid way to delete outliers is to drop all entries which are larger than the mean + 2 or (in your case if you don't want to delete too many entries) 3 standard deviations (i.e. > M + 3SD).